# Assigning to a hasMany relationship in Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to get my head around Ember Data models and have an issue trying to assign a collection of objects found using `store.findAll()` to a `hasMany` relationship of an ember data model.

I have two models defined:

```
App.Leaf = DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    branch: DS.belongsTo('App.Branch')
});

App.Branch = DS.Model.extend({
    lotsOfLeaves: DS.hasMany('App.Leaf')
});
```

If I assign the relationship as part of `createRecord()`

```
    App.store.loadMany(App.Leaf,[
        { id: 1, text: "Hello, I'm leaf 1", branch_id: 1 },
        { id: 2, text: "Hello, I'm leaf 2", branch_id: 1 }
    ]);
    var allLeaves = App.store.findAll(App.Leaf);
    var oneBranch = App.Branch.createRecord({ id: 1, lotsOfLeaves: allLeaves });
```

then it fails (silently) as `oneBranch.get('lotsOfLeaves.length')` is `0`.

Similarly, it fails silently if I assign the relationship after the association:

```
    var all = App.store.findAll(App.Leaf);
    oneBranch.set('lotsOfLeaves', all);
```

I understand that I can use `pushObject()` on `oneBranch.get('lotsOfLeaves')` to add each leaf individually but is that the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MutableArray class also defines a pushObjects() method that you ought to be able to use to add all of them at once.

Documentation is here: http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.MutableArray.html#method=pushObjects

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks @MikeHickman. Although, I was hoping to take advantage of the binding you get when using something like `var autoupdate = App.store.findAll(...)` were any CRUD operations are automatically reflected. So in this case `oneBranch.get('lotsOfLeaves')` would always contain all `App.Leaf` objects in the system.  Looks like I'll have to manually manage that.

Comment: Also, would be nice if attempting to assign something to the association failed with a message of some sort. But hopefully that will be improved over time.